# Schneider EGX100 Gateway with AB PLC 5 series

Tags: measurement, programmable-logic, plc, power-meter

I was investigating hooking up Modbus devices to an AllenBradley PLC 5/40E using a Schneider Electric EGX100 Ethernet gateway.

I can access the web server on the gateway device and monitor the slave devices. However, I couldn't figure out how to write values to the devices.

I would assume that this configuration is useful for monitoring only but that would sort of defeat the purpose. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or resources that I could look through?

Comment: Saad, I know it was awhile ago, but any information you have might really help. We are looking to do a similar task. Read data from our EGX100 into a AB controllogix processor. I have 2 questions about your method above:
1) Do you remember if the EGX100 had to be set to a slave or master device?
2) How did you setup the appropriate read/write packets? For example, I have an EGX100, as a master, with devices 2-9 on them. How do I setup a read command to read data from device 2? I assume first add the EGX100 to my I/O tree, giving it a "Generic Ethernet Module" type. I'm not sure how many bytes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. I figured it out. The steps to do this are as follows:

1. Setup Modbus TCP/IP filtering on the EGX100 through the webserver access to enable the Master device (PLC or PC) to have read write access. To do this you need the IP of the master.
2. Setup the appropriate read / write packets from the master giving careful consideration to the Unit ID parameter. This will define which slave the command is sent to.
3. Automate :-)

I think its also worth noting that the Schneider provides a Web Page Generator utility that can be used to define slave device specific web pages on the EGX100 (and enable the 'Monitoring' tab). This maps the appropriate registers to the actual metering values so for instance, instead of registers 4000 equals 600 you get Power Active = 600.